# Meteor Accounts#resetPassword without logging in

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to call Accounts#resetPassword without logging after the user changes their password?

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: There is a client-side hook [Accounts.onPasswordResetLink](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Accounts-onResetPasswordLink), but unfortunately this runs before the user is logged in.